How to divide 2 D array into 2 different sub arrays?
I am using partition function to divide a 1D array into 2 subarrays with distinct keys. Here is my JS program.
//Partition function
function partition(array, filter) {
  let pass = [], fail = [];
  array.forEach((e, idx, arr) => (filter(e, idx, arr) ? pass : fail).push(e));
  return [pass, fail];
}

//Run it with some dummy data and filter
const [lessThan5, greaterThanEqual5] = partition([0,1,4,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,9,0,1,2,4,6], e => e < 5);

//Output
console.log(lessThan5);
console.log(greaterThanEqual5);  

Output would be:
[
  0, 1, 4, 3, 2,
  4, 0, 1, 2, 4
]
[
  5, 7, 9, 6,
  8, 9, 6
]  

But if I replace 1D array with 2D arrays containing names and marks, the cut off marks is 34. But the program fails.
//Partition function
function partition(array, filter) {
  let pass = [], fail = [];
  array.forEach((e, idx, arr) => (filter(e, idx, arr) ? pass : fail).push(e));
  return [pass, fail];
}

//Run it with some dummy data and filter
const [lessThan5, greaterThanEqual5] = partition([
    {
    name: "Mike",
    marks: 40
  },
  {
    name: "Suzan",
    marks: 20
  },
  {
    name: "David",
    marks: 90
  },
  {
    name: "Peter",
    marks: 32
  }
], e => e < 34);

//Output
console.log(lessThan5);
console.log(greaterThanEqual5);  

Output will be:
[]
[
  { name: 'Mike', marks: 40 },
  { name: 'Suzan', marks: 20 },
  { name: 'David', marks: 90 },
  { name: 'Peter', marks: 32 }
]  

How can I fix that?

How to debug small programs StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story.

The value passed into the filter function is an object with name and marks, so you need to do e.marks < 34:


//Partition function
function partition(array, filter) {
  let pass = [], fail = [];
  array.forEach((e, idx, arr) => (filter(e, idx, arr) ? pass : fail).push(e));
  return [pass, fail];
}

//Run it with some dummy data and filter
const [lessThan5, greaterThanEqual5] = partition([
    {
    name: "Mike",
    marks: 40
  },
  {
    name: "Suzan",
    marks: 20
  },
  {
    name: "David",
    marks: 90
  },
  {
    name: "Peter",
    marks: 32
  }
], e => e.marks < 34);

//Output
console.log(lessThan5);
console.log(greaterThanEqual5);  



